# Listings custom counter

Tags: listings

I've wanted to create custom listings style with its own counter. The problem I have right now is that the counter is not increased by 1 but by 2.

Here is an example:
Output: First listings counter is 2 and second one is 4.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

% Colors
\definecolor{captioncolor}{cmyk/RGB/HTML}{0,0,0,.4/181,181,181/B5B5B5}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.92}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}
\definecolor{identifiercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{stringrcolor}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}

\newcounter{javacounter}
\stepcounter{javacounter}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{captioncolor}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
    format = listing,
    labelfont = white,
    textfont = white
    }
    
\lstdefinestyle{Java}{
    basicstyle = \linespread{1.1}\mdseries,
    backgroundcolor =  \color{backgroundcolor},
    breaklines = true,
    commentstyle = \color{commentcolor},
    identifierstyle = \color{identifiercolor},    
    keywordstyle = \color{keywordcolor},
    language = Java,
    literate =
        {\_}{}{0\discretionary{\_}{}{\_}}
        {Ä}{{\"A}}1
        {Ö}{{\"O}}1
        {Ü}{{\"U}}1
           {ä}{{\"a}}1
           {ö}{{\"o}}1
        {ü}{{\"u}}1
        {ß}{{\ss}}1,
    morekeywords = {assert},
    numbers = left,
    numbersep = 5pt,
    numberstyle=\color{numbercolor},
    showspaces = false,
    showstringspaces = false,
    showtabs = false,
    stringstyle=\color{stringrcolor},
    tabsize = 4,
    title = Java~(\thejavacounter):~\lst@@caption\stepcounter{javacounter},
    xleftmargin = \parindent
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Java]
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Java]
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `singlelinecheck=false` to the caption options for `lstlisting`.

Comment: I can't find \providecaptionname in any package I have installed.

Comment: It's defined in KOMA-Script: `tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty:\newcommand*{\providecaptionname}{%`

But I don't see why switching the single-line-check off for listings affects the usage of `\providecaptionname`, especially since your example code does not use a KOMA-Script class. Could you please update your example so it shows the problem? This would be kind.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a `java` environment to move the `\stepcounter` outside `lstlisting`.  See page 43 of manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

% Colors
\definecolor{captioncolor}{cmyk/RGB/HTML}{0,0,0,.4/181,181,181/B5B5B5}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.92}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}
\definecolor{identifiercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{stringrcolor}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}

\newcounter{javacounter}

\lstnewenvironment{java}{\stepcounter{javacounter}%
  \lstset{style=Java}}{}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{captioncolor}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
    format = listing,
    labelfont = white,
    textfont = white
    }
    
\lstdefinestyle{Java}{
    basicstyle = \linespread{1.1}\mdseries,
    backgroundcolor =  \color{backgroundcolor},
    breaklines = true,
    commentstyle = \color{commentcolor},
    identifierstyle = \color{identifiercolor},    
    keywordstyle = \color{keywordcolor},
    language = Java,
    literate =
        {\_}{}{0\discretionary{\_}{}{\_}}
        {Ä}{{\"A}}1
        {Ö}{{\"O}}1
        {Ü}{{\"U}}1
           {ä}{{\"a}}1
           {ö}{{\"o}}1
        {ü}{{\"u}}1
        {ß}{{\ss}}1,
    morekeywords = {assert},
    numbers = left,
    numbersep = 5pt,
    numberstyle=\color{numbercolor},
    showspaces = false,
    showstringspaces = false,
    showtabs = false,
    stringstyle=\color{stringrcolor},
    tabsize = 4,
    title = Java~(\thejavacounter):~,
    xleftmargin = \parindent
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{java}
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
\end{java}

\begin{java}
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
\end{java}

\end{document}
```